# C# - How to move multiple items up and down inside listbox (Windows Form)

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a ListBox in a Windows Form application.
I easily move single items up and down in the list box with this script:

```
int newIndex = inputFiles.SelectedIndex + direction;

if (newIndex < 0)
   newIndex = inputFiles.Items.Count-1;

if (newIndex >= inputFiles.Items.Count)
    newIndex = 0;

object selected = inputFiles.SelectedItem;

inputFiles.Items.Remove(selected);
inputFiles.Items.Insert(newIndex, selected);
inputFiles.SetSelected(newIndex, true);
```

How can I move multiple selected items? Thank you all!

Comment: Do the same in a loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy the selected indexes into an array, you can loop through the items and update the indexes appropriately:

```
private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  listBox1.BeginUpdate();
  int[] indexes = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>().ToArray();
  if (indexes.Length > 0 && indexes[indexes.Length - 1] < listBox1.Items.Count - 1) {
    for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i > -1; --i) {
      if (indexes.Contains(i)) {
        object moveItem = listBox1.Items[i];
        listBox1.Items.Remove(moveItem);
        listBox1.Items.Insert(i + 1, moveItem);
        listBox1.SetSelected(i + 1, true);
      }
    }
  }
  listBox1.EndUpdate();
}

private void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  listBox1.BeginUpdate();
  int[] indexes = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>().ToArray();
  if (indexes.Length > 0 && indexes[0] > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; ++i) {
      if (indexes.Contains(i)) {
        object moveItem = listBox1.Items[i];
        listBox1.Items.Remove(moveItem);
        listBox1.Items.Insert(i - 1, moveItem);
        listBox1.SetSelected(i - 1, true);
      }
    }
  }
  listBox1.EndUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specific method that moves a List in a listbox. There is an AddRange() that sets it all to the bottom of the list though.

You might try making your own InsertRange() something like this.

```
List<object> toInsert = new List<object>();
toInsert.Add(selected);


InsertRange(int startIndex){
     foreach(object o in toInsert){
          inputFiles.Items.Insert(startIndex, o);
          startIndex++;
     }
}
```

That might not work exactly but, I think this might be what your asking for.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension allow move with multiple selected items 
/// </summary>
static class ListBoxExtension {
    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the selected items up one level
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xListBox"></param>
    public static void MoveUp(ListBox xListBox) {
        if(xListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
            if(xListBox.SelectedIndices[0] > 0) {
                foreach(int i in xListBox.SelectedIndices) {
                    object NewItem = xListBox.Items[i];
                    xListBox.Items.Remove(NewItem);
                    xListBox.Items.Insert(i - 1, NewItem);
                    xListBox.SelectedItem = NewItem;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the selected items one level down
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xListBox"></param>
    public static void MoveDown(ListBox xListBox) {
        if(xListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
            int LastSelectedIndex = xListBox.SelectedIndices[xListBox.SelectedIndices.Count - 1];
            int LastIndex = xListBox.Items.Count - 1;

            if(LastSelectedIndex < LastIndex) {
                foreach(int i in xListBox.SelectedIndices) {
                    object NewItem = xListBox.Items[i];
                    xListBox.Items.Remove(NewItem);
                    xListBox.Items.Insert(i + 1, NewItem);
                    xListBox.SelectedItem = NewItem;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please can you add a brief explanation to your amazing code